# How can I use this protected member function to get the wanted output

Tags: c++

I am not able to get the following output while using protected member function. By defining the function as public I get the right output below, but I want to set it as protected. 
The intended function is marked with (1) in Medium.hpp.

Trying to use Medium::print() in Buch.cpp won't give me the right output.

---

Buch

Titel:     C++: das umfassende Handbuch

Verlag:    Galileo Press

Jahr:      2014

Ausleiher: undef

Autor:     Jürgen Wolf

---

Buch

Titel:     C++ - der Einstieg

Verlag:    Wiley

Jahr:      2014

Ausleiher: undef

Autor:     Arnold Willemer

---

main.cpp:

```
#include <clocale>
#include "Bibliothek.hpp"
#include "Buch.hpp"
#include "DVD.hpp"
#include "Student.hpp"
#include "Dozent.hpp"
#include "test.hpp"
int main() {
    // Umlaute etc. in der Konsole zulassen
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    // Bibliothek mit 100 Plätzen initialisieren
    //Bibliothek bib(100);
    // Bücher und DVDs erstellen


    Buch b1("C++: das umfassende Handbuch", "Jürgen Wolf",
        "Galileo Press", 2014);
    b1.print();
    Buch b2("C++ - der Einstieg", "Arnold Willemer", "Wiley", 2014);
    b2.print();

}
```

Buch.cpp

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include "Medium.hpp"
#include "test.hpp"
#include <iomanip>
// Klasse für die Bücher als Spezialisierung von Medium
class Buch: public Medium{
    // Autor(en) des Buches
    string autor;
    Medium medium;

public:
    // Standardkonstruktor
    Buch(string t = "", string a = "", string v = "", int jahr = 0) 
    : medium(t, v, jahr )
    , autor(a)
    {
    };
    // das Buch auf der Konsole ausgeben
    void print() const
    {
        cout << "-----------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "Buch" << endl;
        //medium.print(); this is logically not working while using protected functions
        // Medium::print() is also not giving my the right output.
        cout << setw(11) << "Autor: " << autor << endl;

    }

};
```

Medium.hpp:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include "Datum.hpp"
#include "Person.hpp"
using namespace std;

class Medium {
    // Titel des Mediums
    const string titel;
    // Verlag, der das Medium herausgibt
    const string verlag;
    // Jahr, in dem das Medium veröffentlicht wurde
    const int jahr;
    // Typ des Mediums (z.B. Buch, DVD, ...)
    // wird von den abgeleiteten Klassen festgelegt
    const string typ;
    // ausgeliehen von
    Person* ausleiher;
    // ausgeliehen am
    Datum von;
    // ausgeliehen bis
    Datum bis;

public:
    // Konstruktor
    Medium(string t="", string v = "", int j = 0,
        string typ = "undef") :titel(t), verlag(v), jahr(j), typ(typ) {};
    // Titel zurückliefern
    string getTitel() const;
    // Typ zurückliefern
    string getTyp() const;
    // Ausleiher zurückliefern
    Person* getAusleiher() const;
    // das Mediuem "ausleihen", d.h. Person p, von und bis eintragen
    void ausleihen(Person& p, Datum von, Datum bis);


    //protected:                       (1)                                                                          

    int cons_1 = 11;
    void print() const {
        cout << setw(cons_1) << left << "Titel: " << titel << endl;
        cout << setw(cons_1) << "Verlag: " << verlag << endl;
        cout << setw(cons_1) << "Jahr: " << jahr << endl;
        cout << setw(cons_1) << "Ausleiher: " << typ << endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: @anonymous Thanks but so I could define directly the function as public xD.

Comment: Why do you have a `medium` object in your `Buch` class, as well as deriving from `Medium`?  You seem to be having problems when mixing the two.

Comment: That is a good question thank you, I will do some changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `Medium` objects contained within your `Buch` class.  One of them is the base class, the other is the `medium` member variable.  You only need one of them.  Since `Medium` has protected members, you should use the base class and get rid of the member variable `medium`.  This is because you can access protected members of the class from a derived class, but cannot access protected members of a member variable.

The `Buch` constructor initializes the `medium` member variable, but not the base class.  To construct the base class, list its type (instead of the member variable name) in the constructor initializer list.

```
Buch(string t = "", string a = "", string v = "", int jahr = 0) 
: Medium(t, v, jahr)
, autor(a)
```

You will then be able to call `Medium::print` and see the expected output from it.  Since `medium` is not used, you can then get rid of it.

(As a side note, your original constructor `Buch(): medium(), autor()` would construct the base class, then the `autor` member, then the `medium` member because that is the order they are declared in.  This could lead to confusion if the constructor for `medium` would depend on the value in `autor`.  Some compiler will issue a warning if the order in the iniitlaizer list is not the one used to initialize variables.)

Answer (score 1):

To call the `print` function in the base class, it normally suffices to write:

```
print();
```

However, in this case, the derived class also has a function called `print`. Therefore, in order to specify that we mean the base class function, we need to qualify it with the name of the base class:

```
Medium::print();
```

If this is not giving the correct output, you have a bug. You might consider stepping through your code with a debugger in order to determine where the bug occurs. If this fails to uncover the bug, you could consider posting another Stack Overflow question which includes a *minimal* piece of code that suffices to reproduce the issue, together with a description of the expected and actual output.

Comment: Thanks, but using 
```Medium::print();``` gives my no error, only the output is wrong.